# Pass List array as params to Android AsynTask

Tags: android, eclipse, types

I have a small huge problem in my android app, I'm trying to pass an array list to the asynctask to post some data to an external api. But eclipse is allways returning a data type error and I cannot figure how to pass the params from the activity to the ASyncTask. Please help

```
  public void Login(View view){
    String usern = username.getText().toString();
    String pwd = password.getText().toString();

    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", usern));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", pwd));                
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("external-login", "true"));

    if(isNetworkAvailable()){
        GetAxiomaCredentials axiomacredentials = new GetAxiomaCredentials();
        axiomacredentials.execute();
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(this, "Network is not available.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

So there I can pass the nameValuePairs to execute as parameter but I get a bad type error from the AsyncTask Private class

```
  private class GetAxiomaCredentials extends AsyncTask<ArrayList<String>, Integer, String>{

    private static final String POST_URL = "http://192.168.0.105/index.php/r=rsite/heartbeat";

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(ArrayList<String>... params) {
        int responseCode = -1;
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(POST_URL);
        try {
            // Add your data
            ArrayList<String> data = params[0];
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(data));

            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        }

        return "Code: " + responseCode;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {

    }

    public void postData(String name, String email, String password,String mobile) {
        // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header

    }
}
```

The eclipse compile error I'm getting is in this line:

```
  ArrayList<String> data = params[0];
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(data));
```

So how can i fix this to pass all parameters from the Login action in the activity to the AsyncTask?
thanks

Comment: Where are you passing it to the `AsyncTask`? I just see you're calling execute but not the way you're trying to pass it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the input into doInBackground to ArrayList. That will remove the cast exception.

```
private class GetAxiomaCredentials extends AsyncTask<Object, Integer, String>{
...
```

Change ArrayList to Object

```
protected String doInBackground(Object... params) {
    int responseCode = -1;
    List<NameValuePair> data = (List<NameValuePair>) params[0];
    ...
```

Then when you call the execute, pass in the nameValuePairs

```
if(isNetworkAvailable()){
    GetAxiomaCredentials axiomacredentials = new GetAxiomaCredentials();
    axiomacredentials.execute(nameValuePairs);
```

Comment: I got cannot cast from ArrayList<Object> to List<NameValuePair>

Comment: It's generally a bad idea to simply use Object as a generic parameter. You really shouldn't do that. I'd also advice against using parameters in the execute() method - it gets increasingly complex if you have more than one. It's much better to use a class constructor with parameters, as suggested in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Simply add a constructor to the `GetAxiomaCredentials` class. The constructor should take the `List` object as a parameter, then store it in a class variable and then use it in `doInBackground()`.

Something along the lines of this:

```
private class GetAxiomaCredentials extends AsyncTask<ArrayList<String>, Integer, String> {

private List<NameValuePair> nvp;

public GetAxiomaCredentials(List<NameValuePair> nvp) {
this.nvp = nvp;
}

/*
use this.nvp in doInBackground(), onPostExecute(), etc...
*/

}
```

And do the following in your main class:

```
GetAxiomaCredentials axiomacredentials = new GetAxiomaCredentials(nameValuePairs);
axiomacredentials.execute();
```

**Update:**

There's no constructor for `UrlEncodedFormEntity` that takes a `List<String>` object. It only accepts `List<? extends NameValuePair>`. That's why it won't compile.

Comment: please check updated code and description of the problem. regards

Comment: So what do I have to do to fix it?

Comment: You can start by using what I wrote in the first part of the answer, and then use the `this.nvp` field instead of the data field in `httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(data))`.